# Static code analysis: check if statement is followed by another statement

Tags: java, checkstyle, findbugs, pmd, static-code-analysis

We recently implemented checkstyle, pmd and findbugs in our development environment. No the question raised, if there is a posibility to check (with any of these tools) that a certain statement oder method call, always has to be followed by another method call later in the code block.

Example:

```
String s = SomeUtil.someMethod("abc");
```

Now I want to get a marker of any sort, that this statement is not followed by another predefined statement:

```
System.out.println(s);
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not possible out of the box with either of the three tools. All three would allow you to write a custom detector which does this.

Comment: @ThomasJensen do you know a easy to understand tutorial or do you have yourself some recommendations how you would do such a thing?

Comment: Try http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/writingchecks.html (for Checkstyle)